# List all skipped tests with PHPUNIT

Tags: php, phpunit

I have searched and read the docs, or at least I think I have, but I have been unable to find if there a way to get a list of all the skipped tests with PHPUNIT?

Is this possible?

Comment: Use the verbose option. Not exactly a list but you can view the skipped and incomplete tests

Comment: I see the `logIncompleteSkipped` in the logging configuration section [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) but I haven't never try....

Comment: It looks like verbose is the only way to get the list from the command line and that [sebastian is not going to add that functionality](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/625). Ideally I'd like to skip running all of the tests and just get a list, but verbose is good, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You could get something close using awk:

`phpunit -v | awk '/skipped tests/,/Tests\:/'`

This will output a list from the start of `There are x skipped tests` to the end of the output with the summary line

Answer (score 2):

With PHPUnit 10:

```bash
phpunit --display-skipped
```

or within the `phpunit.xml`

```xml
<phpunit
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/10.1/phpunit.xsd"
  bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
  colors="true"
  displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerDeprecations="true"
  displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerNotices="true"
  displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerWarnings="true"
  displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerErrors="true"
  displayDetailsOnSkippedTests="true"
>
```